# Use sympy to find coefficients

Tags: python, sympy

I have some equation 0 = c1*f(x,y,z) +c2*g(x,y,z)

I would like for sympy to find c1,c2 as a function of y,z

There is an solution that exists for c1,c2, just I am not sure how to get sympy to find it.

I have tried

```
from sympy import *
# definitions
theta, phi, psi = symbols('theta phi psi')
aa, ab, ac, bb, bc, cc, c1, c2 = symbols('aa ab ac bb bc cc c1 c2')
a, b, c, R = symbols('a b c R')
lab = ['x', 'y', 'z']

# direction cosine matrix
R1 = Matrix([[cos(psi),-sin(psi),0],[sin(psi),cos(psi),0],[0,0,1]])
R2 = Matrix([[cos(theta),0,sin(theta)],[0,1,0],[-sin(theta),0,cos(theta)]])
R3 = Matrix([[cos(phi),-sin(phi),0],[sin(phi),cos(phi),0],[0,0,1]])

DCM = R1*R2*R3
alpha = Matrix([[aa,ab ,ac ], [ab, bb, bc], [ac, bc, cc]])
mu = Matrix([a, b, c])

muLab = DCM*mu
alphaLab = DCM*alpha*DCM.T
#R = aa/cc
# lab frame
chi2 = MutableDenseNDimArray(zeros(27), (3,3,3))
for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    for j in [0, 1, 2]:
        for k in [0, 1, 2]:
            chi2[i,j,k] = alphaLab[i,j]*muLab[k]

norm = 4*pi**2
xxz = simplify(integrate(chi2[0,0,2], (phi, 0, 2*pi), (psi, 0, 2*pi))/norm)
xzx = simplify(integrate(chi2[0,2,0], (phi, 0, 2*pi), (psi, 0, 2*pi))/norm)
zzz = simplify(integrate(chi2[2,2,2], (phi, 0, 2*pi), (psi, 0, 2*pi))/norm)

print(solve((c1*xxz-c2*xzx-zzz),c1,c2))
```

Which does not work, since it gives solutions for c1, and c2 that are not constant with respect to theta, although a solution without theta does exist.

To illustrate what I mean here is a more simple version of the problem

```
xxz2 = cc*c*(1/2)*((1+R)*cos(theta)-(1-R)*(cos(theta)**3))
xzx2 = cc*c*(1/2)*(1-R)*(cos(theta)-cos(theta)**3)
zzz2 = cc*c*(R*cos(theta)+(1-R)*cos(theta)**3)

print(solve((c1*xxz2-c2*xzx2-zzz2),c1,c2,check=False))
```

Which gives no solution for c1,c2 without theta, but if I let c1 be 1/R
then

```
print(solve(((1/R)*xxz2-c2*xzx2-zzz2))))
```

It correctly finds

```
[(c1, 2.0 + 1/R)]
```

So i am wondering why it can't find this solution without me forcing it to and if there is a way to force the solver to find it

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format your code or use the backtick character. Also please include your current output

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind sharing the full code with which you tried to solve the equation? Is the following snippet doing what you need?

```
from sympy import Symbol, Function, Eq
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

c1 = Symbol('c1')
c2 = Symbol('c2')

g = Function('g')(x, y, z)  # g is an undefined function of x, y, z
f = Function('f')(x, y, z)  # f is an undefined function of x, y, z

eq = Eq(c1*f +c2*g, 0)  # defines equation which we want to solve

solve(eq, c1, c2)  # [(-c2*g(x, y, z)/f(x, y, z), c2)]
```

Comment: Hi Peter! Running your code snippet gives me `NameError: name 'xxz2' is not defined`

Comment: should be fixed sorry

Comment: Have you printed (c1*xxz-c2*xzx-zzz) and does it show the formula you were expecting?

Comment: it does, I am just not sure how to force it to find a solution without theta

Answer (score 0):

If you collect terms wrt function of theta you get something like `cos(theta)*(A*cos(theta)**2 + B*sin(theta)**2 + C)`. If this is to be zero and have no dependence on `theta` then doesn't this mean that `A = B` and `A = -C`? Requiring that to be so gives the following solution.

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> <your code>
>>> q = c1*xxz+c2*xzx-zzz
>>> D = q.expand().as_coefficients_dict(theta)
>>> A=cos(theta)**3;B=sin(theta)**2*cos(theta);C=cos(theta)
>>> sol = Dict(solve((D[A]-D[B],D[A]+D[C]),c1,c2))
>>> reps = dict(zip(sol.free_symbols, numbered_symbols('x')))
>>> sol.xreplace(reps)
{
x0: (-2*x2*x6 - 2*x6*x7 - 2*x6*x9)/(x1*x5 - x2*x6 + x4*x8 - x6*x9),
x3: (-2*x1*x5 - 2*x4*x8 - 2*x6*x7)/(x1*x5 - x2*x6 + x4*x8 - x6*x9)}
>>> reps
{c1: x3, c2: x0, bc: x1, aa: x2, a: x4, b: x5, c: x6, cc: x7, ac: x8, bb: x9}
```

Comment: Hi smichr I added some more clarification to the problem, I am just not sure how to get the solver to find an already existing solution for c1,c2

Comment: Your problem is ill-posed in that you are asking for the solution for two coefficients based on a single equation. That means you know something that you aren't telling (so to speak). If you factor your expression and then replace `cos(theta)**2` with `1-x` and then use `solve_undetermined_coeffs(_, (c1,c2), x)` you will get the answer I think you are seeking, e.g. in your second example, `y = c1*xxz2-c2*xzx2-zzz2; solve_undetermined_coeffs(factor_terms(y).subs(cos(theta)**2,1-x),(c1,c2),x)->{c1: 1/R, c2: (2.0*R + 1.0)/R}`. This works if you let `y=c1*xxz-c2*xzx-zzz`, too.